# Swapping Hard Drives And Moving Data

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

So my hard drive is failing, and I'm getting a new one. I just did a fresh install of Win7 a few months ago, and I since it's a relatively fresh install, I was hoping I can just move my data to the new drive. I know there are many software programs that clone/backup drives, but I have a copy of TrueImage 2010, and I would like to use that (but I am open to better options). Below is my plan. I would like to know if there's a flaw in it so I can catch it before the point of no return (i.e., I got a new drive installed, but no way to restore my data).

- Backup my C: drive with TrueImage (It won't let me use the "Clone" feature since it does not detect 2 drives on my machine).
- Install new drive
- Partition drive (?)
- Use the TrueImage Boot Disc to restore from backup

Comment: True Image works well, I have used it since version 6, it has a "clone" feature that works very well.
You can make a bootable CD in Acronis, its called Media Builder, then boot from that CD and clone the old drive to the new one. When done disconnect the old drive and boot into the new one.



If you are just wanting to move data you can use copy and paste, programs however cannot be done this way.

User Guide
http://download.acronis.com/pdf/TrueImage2010_UserGuide.en.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Acronis TrueImage is very powerful. I'm mostly familiar with their live cd. If you are having trouble cloning your drive, first try their live CD before giving up on them. Also make sure that you have both drives hooked up properly and that both drives show up properly in the BIOS. It should let you clone from the live cd.

These are other good backup tools that I am aware of that you can try if you don't like Acronis.

[PING](http://ping.windowsdream.com/)

[Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp)

[CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: I'm working on a laptop. Not sure I can hook up both drives at the same time. As such, True Image won't let me clone.

Comment: @RHPT Ah ok. I use a SATA or IDE to USB converter for that. You can also take out the drive from the laptop and hook it up to a PC. If it is SATA, It'll use the same connectors as PC hard drives. If it is an IDE drive, you'll need a connection converter.

Comment: @RHPT But yes your process should work if you have a good place to put the backup that you'll have access to when you are ready to do the restore (network drive?). Acronis has an option to automatically resize the partitions proportionately for the new drive so repartitioning might not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you purchased Trueimage, however, if it is not straight forward and you are having problems, I would go with a free (and known-good/working) solution.

Personally I would use [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) which is one of my favourite tools.

Simply boot in to it then select the drive and choose copy, then select the new drive and do paste followed by clicking apply.

Another tool to use, which I know a lot of people are using now is [Easeus Disk Copy](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/). I personally do not like it as much, but it works - and if you do not like Gparted, it is nice to have a few options!